# Отправка почтового сообщения с двумя полями

Tags: php

Подскажите, какой будет код, если мне нужна простая функция отправки mail(), чтобы было 2 поля (тема и сообщение) и чтобы была кнопка отправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Подскажите, какой будет код

Код будет такой.

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

А форму ну сам напиши, осталось то дело за малым! А то вопрос будет удален! по причине "**Работа За Автора**"

Comment: А форма для заполнения?